# Facebook Like button event do not work

Tags: facebook-like

There are many POST indicating that once a user click on your Like button, it arises an event that you can catch like the next code:

> ```
>     window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
> ```

```
        //Your app details here
        FB.init({appId: '110981675649741', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});

        FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) {

            alert('You just liked '+href);

        });

        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
```

It seems that now, this do not work.

Does anyone know why? Did Facebook team change the way you get such event?

Comment: Is this code on a Facebook fan page?

Answer (score 10):

Use this code.

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({ appId: 'AppID', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true });
        FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function (href, widget) {
            // Do something, e.g. track the click on the "Like" button here
           // alert('You just liked ' + href);
           // alert('You just liked ' + widget);
            window.location = "http://www.google.com";
        });
    };
    (function () {
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.type = 'text/javascript';
        e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        e.async = true;
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    } ());
//-->
</script>
```

It will work.

Thanks